# Open itinerary on iOS device with ionic 2

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic2, maps

I try to open native map of an iOS with an itinerary.

With Android I use this :

```
openNativeMap() {
    var coords = this.group.latitude + "," + this.group.latitude;
    let address_to_request = this.group.address + "+" +  this.group.city;
    window.open("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + coords + "&daddr="+ address_to_request +"&f=d&mode=driving");
    return;
}
```

It works on android but obviously not on ios.

So I found this solution :

```
openNativeMap() {
    var coords = this.group.latitude + "," + this.group.latitude;
    let address_to_request = this.group.address + "+" +  this.group.city;
    window.open('maps://?q=' + 'MyLocation' + '&saddr=' + '200' + ',' + '200' + '&daddr=' + coords, '_system');
    return;
}
```

I tried to run it on my iOS device, but when I run this function, nothing append.

**Q :** How can I open native iOS maps application like I do it for android ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

I write this code in my .ts file :

```
openNativeMap() {
    var coords = this.group.latitude + "," + this.group.longitude;
    let url: string = "maps://maps.apple.com/?q=" + coords;
    let address_to_request = this.group.address + "+" +  this.group.city;
    window.location.href = url;
    return;
  }
```

And I add this line in my config.xml

```
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
```

It works fine.